# Are local rings of non-singular curves noetherian integral domains?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $P$ be a point on a nonsingular curve $Y$, then the local ring $\mathcal{O}_P$ is a regular local ring of dimension one.

Hartshorne gives the following theorem:

> Let $A$ be a noetherian local domain of dimension one. Then $A$ is a
>   discrete valuation ring if and only if $A$ is a regular local ring.

Hartshorne uses this theorem to immediately conclude that $\mathcal{O}_P$ must be a discrete valuation ring. However, I don't see how the condition that $\mathcal{O}_P$ also be noetherian and an integral domain was satisfied.

Why is $\mathcal{O}_P$ noetherian and an integral domain?

Comment: yes, I had similar issues because I attempted to read Hartshorne before reading about commutative algebra. I recommend reading Atiyah-Macdonald and Eisenbud's commutative algebra book more or less in parallel while reading Hartshorne. I will try to answer your question in my next comment.

Comment: In I.3 he shows that the local rings on a variety are nonzero localizations of noetherian domains, so they remain noetherian domains.

Comment: Are you referring to Theorem 3.2.c?

Comment: I think he is referring to the paragraph before lemma 6.4.

Comment: I think that in this part of the book, by a curve over $k$, Hartshorne means either an affine curve over $k$ or a projective curve over $k$, or Zariski open subsets of such affine or projective curves. For these "objects", it is easy to see that $\mathcal{O}_P$ is noetherian. For example, for an affine curve $C$ in $\mathcal{A}^n$, the "global" ring is $\mathbb{C}[z_1,\cdots,z_n]/I$  (for some ideal $I$) which is noetherian, being the quotient of a noetherian ring, and then $\mathcal{O}_P$ is a localization of that ring at a prime ideal, so it is also noetherian.

Comment: To show that $\mathcal{O}_P$ is an integral domain, here you use that the curve is non-singular (see the previous section).

Comment: Why has nobody mentioned yet, that regular local rings are always domains? That is one of the first results about regular local rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of an algebraic curve being ‘a reduced scheme  of finite type over a field $k$, of dimension $1$’, all its affine sections are reduced $k$-algebras of finite type, hence noetherian rings, of Krull dimension $1$, and noetherianness is preserved by localisation.

On the other hand a non-singular curve has only one irreducible component. We may suppose the curve is a affine curve. Its ring of global sections are therefore an integral domain since for the spectrum of ring is irreducible if and only if it has a generic point, i.e. the  ring has a unique minimal prime ideal. If the ring is reduced, this implies the minimal prime ideal is the zero ideal, i.e. the ring is a domain.

Comment: What do you mean by 'all its sections'? There are noetherian schemes with non-noetherian section rings for some open sets. But the stalks of a (locally) noetherian scheme are of course always noetherian, since they can be computed on an affine neighbourhood.

Comment: @Moos:  Sorry for not having been clear, I meant sections over affine open sets. I've added this precision.